# Exploiting the OOP more effectively

Tags: c#, oop

I'm looking for a possibiltiy to shape my program in a better way and would like to exploit the object-oriented approach more effectively.

```
public ScrollingBackground(int width, int height, int speed, string title, Bitmap path) 
    {

        intBreite = width;
        intHoehe = height;
        intFeinheitDerBewegungen = speed;
        stringTitel = title;
        bitmapBildpfad = path;


        this.Text = title;
        this.Size = new Size(this.intBreite, this.intHoehe);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;


        timerBewegungImage = new Timer();
        timerBewegungImage.Tick += new EventHandler(bewegungImage_XRichtung_Tick);
        timerBewegungImage.Interval = constIntInterval;
        timerBewegungImage.Start();

        ////
        picBoxImage = new PictureBox();
        picBoxImage.Image = global::Flugzeugspiel.Properties.Resources.MyFlugzeug;
        picBoxImage.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
        picBoxImage.SetBounds(100, 100, 125, 50);
        this.Controls.Add(picBoxImage);
        ////

        listPicBoxAufeinanderfolgendeImages = new PictureBox[2];

        imageInWinFormLadenBeginn();

        this.ShowDialog();

    }
```

As you can see the constructor above that the code enclosed by the slashes is located in the constructor ScrollingBackground.

It is important for me that this contructor should contain code only relating to the Scrolling Background but not the image MyFlugzeug.png.
This image (of course the whole code enclosed by the slashes) should be swapped into my main class Flugzeug.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;


    public abstract class Flugzeug : Form
    {

        private PictureBox picBoxImage;     
        protected int lebensanzeige = 10; 




        public virtual void nachObenUntenFliegen(string pathOfMovingObject, int xPositionObject, int yPositionObject, int widthOfObject, int heightOfObject)
        {

                 // The code in the upper constructor enclosed by the slashes should stand here. Here I'd like to ensure the control of the airplane which has to be still programmed. 

        }


        public int getLebensanzeige()
        {

            return lebensanzeige;

        }


        public int getTreffer(int schussstaerke)
        {

            return lebensanzeige = lebensanzeige - schussstaerke;

        }

    }
```

How is it possible to transfer the code from the constructor to the class Flugzeug?

I've tried something but it didn't work.

I've tried sth. like this:

```
    public class MyFlugzeugspiel
        {


            public static void Main()
            {

                MyFlugzeug myPlane = new MyFlugzeug(10);


                ScrollingBackground hintergrund = new ScrollingBackground(1000, 650, 5, "THE FLIGHTER", global::Flugzeugspiel.Properties.Resources.Himmel, myPlane);

...
```

---

```
    public abstract class Flugzeug : Form
        {

            private PictureBox picBoxImage;     
            protected int lebensanzeige = 10; 



            public virtual void nachObenUntenFliegen(string pathOfMovingObject, int xPositionObject, int yPositionObject, int widthOfObject, int heightOfObject)
            {

                picBoxImage = new PictureBox();
                picBoxImage.Image = global::Flugzeugspiel.Properties.Resources.MyFlugzeug;
                picBoxImage.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                picBoxImage.SetBounds(100, 100, 125, 50);
                this.Controls.Add(picBoxImage);


            }

...




 public ScrollingBackground(int width, int height, int speed, string title, Bitmap path, Flugzeug plane) 
    {


        intBreite = width;
        intHoehe = height;
        intFeinheitDerBewegungen = speed;
        stringTitel = title;
        bitmapBildpfad = path;
        this.plane = plane;
        plane.nachObenUntenFliegen("Path", 0, 0, 100, 100);



        this.Text = title;
        this.Size = new Size(this.intBreite, this.intHoehe);
        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedSingle;
        this.MaximizeBox = false;

...
```

But this isn't right, is it? Nothing happens. The airplane won't appear on the Scrolling Background.

Who can help me solving this problem?

Comment: Generally speaking, moving the enclosed bit to the FlugZeug should work as long as you create a proper instance of that FlugZeug either from within the instance of the ScrollingBackground or at the very least make the instance of the FlugZeug accessible to the instance of the ScrollingBackground.
Very generalized start to help you further: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9afc042.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could make a `Control` or `Form` out of your `ScrollingBackground` class, and derive from it (or use it as control) in your `Flugzeug` form.

If you think deriving is the best option, your class signature should look like this:

```
public class ScrollingBackground : Form { }

public class Flugzeug : ScrollingBackground { }
```

If you like a control better, you should expose the required properties from the `ScrollingBackground` class, so you can access them in your `Flugzeug` class.

Comment: I'm gonna check it out! Thanks!